Need Hanger Adapter for Acera Rear Derailleur for Hero Sprint rx2 bicycle frame
First I had the Tourney derailleur. Which is somehow destroyed, and I've lost it. I promptly bought an Acera online, expecting to upgrade. A lot has been spent. Here's the issue: I wasn't aware the previous rear derailleur had an integrated hanger. However, the new one does not have it. I don't think the new Acera will attach without a hanger adaptor. Please advise on how I may get out of this situation. Which hanger adapter should I buy for my Hero Sprint RX2 bicycle?

Judging by the photos I could find online, I believe what you want is a claw derailleur hanger. They are available from several manufacturers and I would think that most bike shops would have one available or could get one quickly.
